# Bing Search API: Narrow by date

Tags: search-engine, bing, bing-api, narrowing

In it's current version, is it possible to use Bing's "Narrow By Date" feature when accessing it's API?

I cannot find any information about how to narrow the results such that it only shows results from the "past 24 hours" or "past week" (and so on).

The website/documentation isn't exactly clear on what I can and cannot do, and how. Do any of you know whether it's possible or not?

I can see on their Advanced Search Keywords page that you can use other narrowing features (region, language, hasfeed, etc.) here: http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-ca/bing/ff808421.aspx

If you need any more context or information please ask. Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: have you had any luck with this?

Comment: I've been fairly busy with other stuff lately, so it's been a while since I've looked into it, but last time I checked it didn't seem like something you could easily do using their API.

Comment: Well, I spent almost 3 hours for this issue as well. It seems to be impossible in the current API. Even using bing while browsing - the "narrow by date" feature is limited to "last 24h", "last week", "last month", "last year" only. I'll be glad to find out I was wrong though.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck on this? I can provide results from News and sort them by Relevance or Date, but I cant narrow the results by Date (Last 24h, last week etc)

Comment: Maybe this can be of any help: http://blog.codefluententities.com/2012/06/26/how-to-re-enable-the-bing-search-engine-narrow-by-date-feature/

Comment: There is a hidden option to narrow web search results by date, by adding the same GET argument Google uses: &tbs=qdr:d (d for day, w for week, m for month). Doubt that works with the API though.

Answer (score 4):

The Bing search API is pretty vague in terms of limiting results and what you can and cannot use.  After testing various words and placement to try and get date to work, I'm fairly certain that there is not a way to use a date to narrow results.